# Three time dimensions and one spatial dimension degeneracy

Tags: relativity, metric-tensor

Is there a sort of degeneracy in the space-time metric for our universe?  What I mean is that it seems you would observe all the same properties of our universe if you simply placed a minus sign in front of the Minkowski Metric.  But are they truly the same?  I am imagining that there could be something similar to degenerate energy states in quantum mechanics, where you get the same energy in one observable for two states that are in fact distinguishable by some other property.

Answer (score 2):

Not degeneracy, just you decide whether you place the negative sign in front or not, and then compute everything without changing it. It's just a convention, like whether you call positive when you loose energy or when you gain it (since somebody does the opposite). The results, in physical terms, are the same.

There are other real 'degenaracies', in what coordinate system or reference frame you use, since the metrics terms then have to be adjusted to the new coordinate system.  If you use a reference frame that is moving you could measure different numbers than the other guy, that's Relativity. Even energy and mass can be different depending on your reference frame (ie, whether moving wrt another), and of course time and distance also. Curvature and other physical entities can be (and are) defined that are independent of the reference frame. Also other entities, like the rest mass (well, measure it in its rest frame), etc.

There's more. Placing a minus in from of x or t leaves the metric the same, but these are called reflections and time inversions. Most physics is symmetric with respect to these, they are called parity (P) and time (T) inversion transformations. It is known that if you invert P, T and charge (C), the physics is the same, it's called CPT conservation. It is known that P is not conserved in the weak interactions, by a very small amount. Pretty stange but it's been known for about 50 or more years.

Comment: Sorry, when you say placing a minus in front of x or t do you mean placing a minus in front of x and t?  Because if you just put the minus in front of the t component wouldn't you just get a euclidean metric, and if you put one in front of the x component wouldn't you just get a 2 time 2 space metric?

Comment: I should have been more explicit. I meant transform x to -x, and/or t to -t. You could do them independently. The metric is unchanged, you just did a reflection and/or time inversion. dx square is unchanged as -1 square is 1. Same for dt square.  Still a 3 plus 1 metric. If you changed the metric as you said, 2 plus 2, you are right that things are different.

Comment: That makes sense.  So am I right in saying there's no real significance to whether you consider the time component of the positive or negatively signed, so long as the spatial dimensions are oppositely signed?

Comment: Correct. Most of the time General Relativity is done using the 3 spatial dimensions as plus and time as minus. But for spinors and the Newman Penrose formalism often the opposite is used, it winds up being just a bit simpler in the equation so. And some books and papers will use one or the other. The physical results are the same regardless of what a you use, it's just a convention. The way to say it is that the metric is of signature 2 or -2, ans the results are the same physics.